# Adding watermark stamp to image inside of WP

Tags: php, wordpress, image, watermark

I have an AJAX call with wordpress where I need to add watermark to image and send it in the email. I'm following [this instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) (and many others here on stackoveflow) to reach desired result, but to no avail, all I'm getting is small black image.

Here is my code

```
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pitchprint.io/previews/" . $project_id . "_1.jpg");
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng(get_site_url() . "/wp-content/themes/porto-child/img/watermark.png");
    
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

    // Output and free memory
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

images paths are correct, and they load fine in the borwser, but for some reason I cannot get this code to work, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code runs as well, I've tested it in local machine.

1. Check your code with static image URL, Make sure it works with static image.
2. Put your image URLs in  tag to make sure your images are work well

I think it has problem with your images.

---

**Edit**: Your image in cloud is not **JPEG**, It's a **PNG** image format,It just has *jpg* extension.
So, Just change this code

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pitchprint.io/previews/" . $project_id . "_1.jpg");
```

To

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pitchprint.io/previews/" . $project_id . "_1.jpg");
```

Comment: Images work well, the path to images open well and without errors.

Comment: Did you check code with static image URL?

Comment: yes I did. The path to the image works well inside html image tag.

Comment: Could you show me `$project_id` and `get_site_url()` values for examine with real data?

Comment: here is the image `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pitchprint.io/previews/031db1e338d4aca350440b4dc164e991_1.jpg`

I'm running local by flywheel, so my `get_site_url()` returns my local dev site, which loads the image perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting black image instead.

Comment: Make sure your images format to be correct. Both original photo and watermark. Use your code according to image formats. Image extension does not matter. File type is important and you should use functions `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagecreatefrompng` according to your image format. It's very very important. At last the only thing left is the watermark photo. Make sure it's a correct png image format because you have used `imagecreatefrompng`. If problem doesn't solve feel free and ask help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "My watermark text";
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$fontSize = 3;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
```

if you what to past image on image use imagecopymerge

Comment: What is your `$image` variable referring to, `imagecreatefromjpeg('somepathtoimage.jpeg')`?

Comment: resource $image. you can use imagecreatefromjpeg, imagecreate,imagecreatefromgif,